# Remove MasterView shadow in UISplitView

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, shadow, uisplitview, uipopoverbackgroundview

I have a UISplitView iPad Application, which shows and hides the MasterView via gestures for swiping left/right. If I make the UITableView background white, it appears as it should.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtv1Q.png

However when I make the UITableView background clear, I see a shadow, presumeably another view with low opacity behind the UITableView.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qgiO.png

**How can I get rid of this shadow?**

I have tried creating UIPopoverBackgroundView and setting self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]; in initWithFrame, but when i assign it:

```
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc {
mainPop = pc;
mainPop.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [clearBG class];
```

}

initWithFrame function is never called, and nothing changes.

Thanks.